# Javafx TextField positions the caret incorrectly after pressing delete key

Tags: javafx, textfield

Try this simple Javafx code:

```
TextField text1 = new TextField("abc");
TextField text2 = new TextField("abc");
HBox root = new HBox(text1, text2);
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

Now if you click on the TextField to position the caret right before "b" character, then if you press DEL key to delete "b" you will notice that often the caret is shifted one character to the left instead staying put:

[image]

[image]

Note: You have to use your mouse to click on "b" to move the caret there. If you use your keyboard arrow keys to move the caret there then this bug won't happen.

You may have to repeat this a few times to be able to see this effect.
In my Windows 10 computer it occurs more than 70% of times.

Is this a known bug? Is there a workaround?

Comment: What version of `JavaFX` are you using?

Comment: I can't duplicate this issue in `JavaFX 14`.

Comment: I get this in both `Javafx 14` and `Javafx 8`. Are you on a Windows machine? Are you sure you first click on the textfield, then press the Delete key without pressing any other key?

Comment: I use Windows 10. Let me try again.

Comment: Yep, first click.

Comment: Still couldn't reproduce? Try a few times by clicking on the 2nd textfield, then click back on the first textfield again and press Delete key. This problem was first reported by the users of my app. For some of them it happens only 50% of times. But I can reliably reproduce it 100% of times now

Comment: Also make sure to press DEL key, not the Backspace key.

Comment: I have been pressing backspace. Yes, it looks like a bug.

Comment: Glad you could duplicate it too. I searched OpenJDK bugs and couldn't find existing bug report. Guess I should make one.

Comment: Note this problem only seems to occur in the first `TextField` for me. Is that true for you as well? Is that why there's two `TextField`s?

Comment: @Slaw for me it's both textFields, but only at index 1 (and only if clicking to that index, not reaching it with navigation) - both fx11 and current dev (had hoped for a magic side-effect of a currently worked-on fix .. but where is magic if we need it ;)

Comment: when reporting, please add a complete [mcve] to relieve the reviewer from having to do it :)

Comment: @Slaw looks like the caretPosition is correct (unchanged) but the caret painted at the wrong position .. that's similar to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8210145 (though the context in that bug is different in having a TextFormatter with filter) - knew I had seen it somewhere/somehow ..

Comment: ookay, looks like it happens in TextFieldSkin around deleteChar/scrollAfterDelete - for some reason it resets the caret's x to 0 if "near" the beginning. Rounding error maybe? Could somebody please check if it happens in non-hdpi contexts as well?

Comment: I added the 2nd textfield as an easy way of re-doing all the steps. i.e. click on the 2nd textfield, then try again. Because originally I thought this problem only occurs upon first time the textfield gets focused. This problem is reproduceable in both textfields for me.

Comment: I could reproduce this problem at index 2 also. In fact I could reproduce it at any index (I tried a longer text at index 10).

Comment: The index does not necessarily reset to 0 in my case. It gets shifted to left so if you try index 10, the result will be at index 9. But as someone already pointed out, this is only a rendering bug. The caret in fact remains at correct position but rendered at wrong index. I filed a bug. Will post the link when it gets assigned one.

Comment: yeah, you are right - it happens at any position, though not 100% reproducible: seems to  never happen if first doing some keyboard navigation and then click and delete. No idea what exactly triggers it.

Comment: have to run now, just in case somebody wants to dig further: tracked the error down to the hitInfo created by the skin (requested by behavior after mouse pressed) - depending on this the execution path is slightly different (only one of it produces the correct result, the other moves the caret after delete). Couldn't find how/why exacty the apparently same (?) mouse event produces different hitInfos ..

Comment: Interesting find. Wonder exactly what's the difference between the two hitInfo objects

Comment: actually, the hitInfo as such seems to be okay (leading flag is on/off depending on where the char is hit), but for some weird reason, later that leading/not is used to move the textNode's caret forward/backward which brings it off-sync with the controls caret which leads (? don't know why exactly) to the visual quirk (which also has the effect of disabling forward keyboard navigation if the skin thinks - correctly, as the control's caret is - it's already at the last)

Answer (score 1):

I reported this issue to OpenJDK:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8248914

The OpenJDK developers have confirmed that this is a real bug.

Comment: great :) Added a reference to this qa

Comment: fyi: priority uppened to p3 - with some luck, might be fixed in fx16 :)

Comment: oh neat! didn't realize you were an OpenJDK contributor! Is there no chance of including the potential fix in fx15?

Comment: there's always a chance - though I doubt it will happen in this case: fx15 is in first rampdown, second starts at the end of the month, so until there's a text expert around and willing to fix it quickly and convince the project lead that it is risk-free ..